# Is it possible to disable Vector Type in Clang?

Tags: clang, llvm, llvm-ir

I want to compile a program using Clang (version 10.0.1) with the following command:

```bash
clang -O3 test.c -o test
```

Checked the result of the IR, I found that there are many variables with the type `llvm::VectorType`. Is it possible for us to disable the existence of `llvm::VectorType` by setting some compilation options? Or can we lower the `llvm::VectorType` to some other basic types like `llvm::IntegerType`?

I checked and tryied the documents of [Vectorizers](https://llvm.org/docs/Vectorizers.html) of LLVM, however the options `-fno-vectorize` and `-fno-slp-vectorize` only work for disabling Loop & SLP Vectorizers and do not remove `llvm::VectorType` variables.